# LSD-SLAM double free or corruption

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to run the LSD-SLAM by https://github.com/kevin-george/lsd_slam/wiki/LSD-SLAM-with-ROS-and-Ubuntu-16.04 using ROS-Melodic and Ubuntu 18.04.
It compiled fine with no errors but when trying to start the lsd_slam_core using this comand: `rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam /image:=/camera/image_raw _calib:=src/lsd_slam/calibration_params` it throws a message and then stops.

This is the message I get: 
`double free or corruption (out)`
`Aborted (core dumped)`

I'm not sure where it dumps the core but I'll attach it if someone could tell me.
I found this [Issue](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam/issues/238) on Github which more or less handles the same error, and there they recommend using another version of Eigen. I installed multiple versions but it didn't run, and I always got the same eror.

Hope someone can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328647/lsd-slam-double-free-or-corruption/) by [MrMinemeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/44067/mrminemeet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok fixed it myself :D it worked
I as stated in the comment on the other answer I wasn't able to compile it on another version because g2o didn't like eigen 3.2.5.
But when only using Eigen 3.2.5 on catkin_make for LSD_SLAM without a problem. 
Here's what I did.
I just sed the variable `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` to the path of the downloaded 3.2.5 one line above the `include_directories` 
[image: image description]

hope this helps someone.

---

Originally posted by [MrMinemeet](https://answers.ros.org/users/44067/mrminemeet/) with karma: 41 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32621/bas/) on 2019-10-30**:
This worked for me. Thanks a lot!